# How do I remove texts from a corpus in R?

Tags: r, data-science, text-mining, tm, quanteda

I'm dividing a long document into chapters using the corpus_segment function in the tm package.

After running the pattern, I'm still left with a couple of unwanted chapters. I'd like to somehow remove these from the corpus.

I've tried looking this up in the documentation, but honestly can't seem to figure out the right way to go about this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tm)
library(readtext)
frp2005 <- readtext("http://www.nsd.uib.no/polsys/data/filer/parti/H9368.html", encoding = "LATIN1")

tmp <- corpus(frp2005)

docvars(tmp, c("parti", "2005")) <- c("frp", 1)

frp_2005 <- tmp %>%
  corpus_segment(
    pattern ="\n[A-Z][a-z].*\\w\n.\\w",
    valuetype = "regex", 
    case_insensitive = FALSE)
```

This code results in the document being divided into 20 chapters, 5 of which I'd like to be removed.

```
          Text Types Tokens Sentences parti 2005
  H9368.html.1   132    231        11   frp    1
  H9368.html.2     4      4         2   frp    1
  H9368.html.3   639   1421        80   frp    1
  H9368.html.4   728   1862       113   frp    1
  H9368.html.5   496   1217        71   frp    1
```

How would i go about removing, say "H9368.html.4" from this corpus?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure your regex is segmenting the text in the way you intended, that was not part of your question, so I will show you what you did ask.  This involves loading the **quanteda** package by the way, and does not require either **tm** or **dplyr**.

Here's how.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.4.3
## Parallel computing: 2 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
## 
## Attaching package: 'quanteda'
## The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
## 
##     View

frp2005 <- readtext::readtext("http://www.nsd.uib.no/polsys/data/filer/parti/H9368.html", encoding = "LATIN1")
tmp <- corpus(frp2005)
docvars(tmp, c("parti", "2005")) <- c("frp", 1)

frp_2005 <- tmp %>%
  corpus_segment(
    pattern = "\n[A-Z][a-z].*\\w\n.\\w",
    valuetype = "regex",
    case_insensitive = FALSE
  )

head(docnames(frp_2005))
## [1] "H9368.html.1" "H9368.html.2" "H9368.html.3" "H9368.html.4"
## [5] "H9368.html.5" "H9368.html.6"
```

Then, just use `corpus_subset()` with an exclusion on the document names that you want to exclude.  For a more general match, you could have used `grepl()` or some other function that returns a logical for the second argument to `corpus_subset()`.

```r
corpus_subset(frp_2005, !docnames(frp_2005) %in% c("H9368.html.4")) %>%
  docnames() %>%
  head()
## [1] "H9368.html.1" "H9368.html.2" "H9368.html.3" "H9368.html.5"
## [5] "H9368.html.6" "H9368.html.7"
```